# Neo4j start trouble

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j can be installed on my 32bit windows OS. But it cannot be activated on my local IE browsers. Is there anyone who meet up the same problem?

[neo4j cannot be accessed in my IE browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6gR7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download [Neo4j Desktop](https://neo4j.com/download/) 
I have nice interface and everything built-in to run database and browser on desktop (even without using windows command prompt).